# Hibernate Compatibility Matrix

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-validator

Could someone please help me finding the latest Hibernate compatibility matrix. I'm specially interested in Hibernate Validator vs Hibernate Core.

The one, I [found](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix) on internet does not seem to be the latest.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such matrix anymore. The wiki page you are referring to is obsolete and not maintained anymore. This page was mainly used pre dependency management (speak pre Maven/Gradle) times.

Regarding compatibility between Hibernate Validator and Hibernate ORM - these two projects are really independent. The only integration between the two is the automatic life cycle based validation which is defined by the JPA and Bean Validation specs.

What is your actual problem? Why do you need to have such a matrix?